# Google Play Store does not open

Tags: google-play-store

i have a alcatel onetouch, since two days ago i try to open the Google Play store, but it does not show up, i looks like it will open but it get closed inmediatly, i don't know why
does anyone can help ?

Comment: Does it show any dialog, something about being stopped or not responding? Have you attempted any troubleshooting so far?

Comment: it does not show absolutely nothing, and i have Google play services installed and running.

Comment: Umm... What do you mean by "does not show absolutely nothing"? Please be clear with your English, colloquial speak doesn't help others to understand what you mean out of context. Did you mean "does not show anything" or "shows something"?

Comment: does not show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean cache and other data to Google Play Services & Google Play Store (Menu-->Configuration-->Application).
If it does not work try to remove updates from google play store.